# How to check If Oembed is empty or not

Tags: php, functions, videos, oembed

We often use the Oembed function provided by the Wordpress to embed media.

I have a condition where I am running a loop to fetch certain posts from a custom post type, but I want to skip posts in which Oembed is empty.

How to check if Oembed is empty or has a URL in meta of single.php.

I tried something like this →

```
<?php $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_oembed', true ) ); ?>
<?php $embed = wp_oembed_get( $url ); ?>
```

## PHP Needed →

Now how to check if `$embed` is empty or not?

## Update as requested →

The front end will be like [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/sitepoint007/empty_post.png), and it pulled by running a WP custom loop like this.

But there can be a situation like this where the OEMBED is empty like [this](https://www.screencast.com/t/PTDnDB23FjR).

So what I want is when such situation exists the loop should exclude that post and for that, we need `if condition` that checks If oembed is empty or not.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`wp_oembed_get()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get)  only works for supported oEmbed providers. The return value is also is a URL of false, as mentioned per codex:

> If $url is a valid url to a supported provider, the function returns
>   the embed code provided to it from the oEmbed protocol. Otherwise, it
>   will return false.

Therefore, is the input is empty, the return value would be false, so you could simply check:

```
if ( $embed ) {
    // Valid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s a little hard to guess what’s your question really is and what exactly you want to check...

If you want to check if $embed is empty, just check it:

```
if ( ! trim($embed) ) {
    // it’s empty
}
```

If you want to check if the $url is empty:

```
if ( ! trim($url) ) {
    // it’s empty
}
```

Comment: I have a video CPT, where video URL needs to be embedded, but if the post is empty w/o video URL in Oembed than that posts need to e exist in the loop while fetching all the posts so I was looking for a condition so that empty posts w/o Oembed should be left without.

Comment: I tried your [solution](https://www.screencast.com/t/JDy4pMdy), but it didn't worked.

Comment: Can you help me to improve the question since you downvoted me.

Comment: @TheWPNovice I’m sure it worked. But I’m almost certain it didn’t do what you wanted - I still have no idea what are you trying to achieve... it’s really hard to guess anything based on your question and the comment above...

Comment: Ok let me try to elaborate. Give me 5  minutes please. Thanks

Comment: Please do. Update your question, so it's a little bit more clear.

Comment: Sir Updated Please check.